# Sort macro and data validation macro

Tags: vba, excel

My plan is to enter data on a specific sheet(List) and automatically sort by alphabetical order, then create a data validation on the first sheet (TicketSheet). 
[image: excel spreadsheet screenshot]

When I enter any date and save I can't open the file again because it crashes.

I developed the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A:$F")) Is Nothing Then


    Dim x As Range
    Set x = Cells(2, Target.Column)
    Dim y As Range
    Set y = Cells(1000, Target.Column)


    If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 6 Then
    Range(x, y).Sort Key1:=Target, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

    End If
    End If

    Call AddData
    Call AddData1
    Call AddData2


End Sub


Sub AddData()

Dim Lrow As Single
Dim Selct As String
Dim Value As Variant

Lrow = Worksheets("List").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Value In Range("A2:A" & Lrow)
    Selct = Selct & "," & Value

Next Value


Selct = Right(Selct, Len(Selct) - 1)

With Worksheets("TicketSheet").Range("C4").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Selct
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub


Sub AddData1()


Dim Lrow1 As Single
Dim Selct1 As String
Dim Value As Variant


Lrow1 = Worksheets("List").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For Each Value In Range("D2:D" & Lrow1)
    Selct1 = Selct1 & "," & Value

Next Value


Selct1 = Right(Selct1, Len(Selct1) - 1)


With Worksheets("TicketSheet").Range("C3").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Selct1
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub

Sub AddData2()


Dim Lrow2 As Single
Dim Selct2 As String
Dim Value As Variant


Lrow2 = Worksheets("List").Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For Each Value In Range("F2:F" & Lrow2)
    Selct2 = Selct2 & "," & Value

Next Value


Selct2 = Right(Selct2, Len(Selct2) - 1)


With Worksheets("TicketSheet").Range("C5").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Selct2
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
End Sub]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to disable events. The [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro is triggered by a change of values. If you are going to start changing values inside a Worksheet_Change then disabling events stops the macro from triggering itself.

Additionally, the **Target** is the cell or cells that have been changed. Your code does not allow for the latter; it only deals with situations where Target is a single cell. For the time being, discard large changes (like those in a row deletion or sort operation).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("$A:$F")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim x As Range, y As Range
        Set x = Cells(2, Target.Column)
        Set y = Cells(1000, Target.Column)

        If Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 6 Then
            'you really should know if you have column header labels or not
            Range(x, y).Sort Key1:=Target, Order1:=xlAscending, _
                             Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, _
                             MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
            Call AddData
            Call AddData1
            Call AddData2
        End If
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That should get you started. I will look deeper into your other sub procedures later but I will remark that it seems like you have an awful lot going on to have initiated by a Worksheet_Change.

Comment: He also has a bracket at the end of the End Sub]

Comment: Thank your for the help so far. The bracket is just a misspelling.