# Automatically sort rows in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automatically sort fields in excel when entering new data. Suppose I have the following data:
1 Pre-Design
2 Design
4 Construction
5 Post-Construction 
If I enter “3 Tender”, it should automatically get sorted and moved to the appropriate place. How can I do this in MS Excel 2013?

My Current Code is as follows but you must run the Macro each time; would prefer it sort automatically:

```
Sub SORTROWS()
Range("A7:AF200").Sort key1:=Range("D7:D200"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("A7:AF" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("D7:D" & lastrow), _
   order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

Comment: Put your code in a Worksheet_Change event.

Comment: Possible dupplicate of [Sort macro and data validation macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35542532/sort-macro-and-data-validation-macro/35544382#35544382).

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Sub ..., use
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
...
End Sub